# URL variable in .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, server

I have the URL: https://www.firstdomain.com

Under the url https://www.firstdomain.com there is a .htaccess with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex awstats.pl
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  https://www.thebestwebsite.com/statistics/seconddomain.com/awstats/$1?lang=en [P,QSA]
```

Until now everything runs correctly.

Now I want to replace dynamically in .htaccess the "**seconddomain.com**" with the one I will have on the browser's URL.

For example, when I will hit the https://www.firstdomain.com/?domain=thirddomain.com
I want the .htaccess to have in RewriteRule the following url:

> https://www.thebestwebsite.com/statistics/thirddomain.com/awstats/$1?lang=en

I have tried with the following .htaccess but with no result:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex awstats.pl
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^domain=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.thebestwebsite.com/statistics/%1/awstats/$1?lang=en [P,QSA]
```

Is there anybody who has a better idea to make it work?

**EXAMPLE #2**

The following example is working for me by 90%:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex awstats.pl

# Check if the referer is https://stats.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://stats\.mydomain\.com [NC]
# If the referer matches, apply this RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://statsdomain.com/_statistics_/anotherdomain.com/awstats/$1 [P,QSA]

# If the referer doesn't match, apply the default RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)domain=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://statsdomain.com/_statistics_/%1/awstats/$1 [P,QSA]
```

My question is how can I leave it as it is (as it is working fine) and replace only "anotherdomain.com" with the value of the URL's variable "domain"?

Comment: Why "a better idea"? Does it work or not? If not, what does that mean _exactly_ ?

Comment: Already said "I have tried with the following .htaccess but with no result" which means it doesn't work. I get the error: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: "it doesn't work" does not help. You now gave the additional information that you received a http 403 (Forbidden) which is _very_ valuable information. I suggest you add that to the question itself.

Comment: It you receive back a 403-forbidden then apparently the rewriting does work. To me this reads as if your application logic refuses the request. Whyever. I could imagine that it does not like proxied requests. Why don't you do a "normal" internal rewrite? Is that second domain served from a separate system, which would explain your usage of the `P` flag (proxy)?

Comment: I have P flag because I don't want to redirect and show the URL "thebestwebsite.com". I want the user to see only the domain firstdomain.com.

Comment: If you serve both host ("domains") from the same http server then there is no need for a redirection. An internal rewrite is the standard approach. It prevents issues with a proxy, especially the efficiency impact you buy when using a proxy: each and every requests results into an additional internal request adding to performance and resource usage.

Comment: I have edited my question. Check example No2 and if you coud help you will be my idol! :)

Comment: It reads to me as if you decided to ignore what I wrote in my last comment... Which is perfectly fine! But then there is little I can do.

Comment: About the specific question you ask in the end of your edit: well, just capture that domain name from the query string and use it as a replacement in the rule below. What you are looking for is done in the following, the last combination of a condition and a rule. Why can't you simply do the same?